# Error while trying to deploy WAR on Tomcat8 on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, ubuntu, tomcat8

I am trying to deploy a .war file using Tomcat8, Apache, and Ubuntu 15.04.  When I click "Select WAR file to upload" in the /manager section of tomcat I get the following error:

> FAIL - Deploy Upload Failed, Exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   /opt/tomcat/webapps/musicStore.war (Permission denied)

How would I fix this?

Comment: chmod to give permissions in full on that folder

Comment: Just chmod 777 everything?

Comment: Open everything to the world? Well - your choice. I'd not do it. Tomcat runs as a specific user. It's ok to just give that user permissions to the directory. Or not use manager - rather copy the file there through the OS

Comment: I'm a newbie.  How would I go about creating the specific user and then giving it permissions to deploy the WAR?

Comment: your /opt/tomcat/webapps directory belongs to someone (execute `ls -l /opt/tomcat/webapps` to see whom it belongs to). While tomcat is running, execute `ps aux | grep catalina` to see which user is running tomcat. You *could* `chown thatuser /opt/tomcat/webapps`. However, for production systems I'd strongly recommend to not have the manager application running and tomcat's own directory writeable to itself. It opens up quite a few attack vectors and is bad practice

Comment: (by the way: on a local dev system, the risk for `chmod 777` is lower and there's a point for doing it. Just be aware of the risk and don't do it to an internet-accessible system)

Comment: Yeah it's a local system but it never hurts to practice best practices whenever possible.  =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting comments to an answer, adding more information:

Your `/opt/tomcat/webapps` directory belongs to *someone* (execute `ls -l /opt/tomcat/webapps` to see whom it belongs to).

While tomcat is running, execute `ps aux | grep catalina` to see which user is running tomcat (depends on the way you start it - might be your own current user). You *could* `chown <thatuser> /opt/tomcat/webapps`. However, for production systems I'd strongly recommend to not have the manager application running and tomcat's own directory writeable to itself. It opens up quite a few attack vectors and is bad practice IMHO

If it's a local development system, comfort typically trumps security - and you might opt for keeping the manager app.

To mitigate the potential manager-app problems in production, at least limit access to known IP-Addresses, keep the user database well maintained (not in tomcat-users.xml with clear text passwords). However, on my production systems, tomcat can not write to its own webapps directory - thus hot deployment of applications through the manager app won't work anyways...

Comment: Thanks for the help!