# how to host JSP pages for free testing

Tags: java, hosting

I've created a web project project using Java, Apache and MySQL on eclipse. Now the thing is that I want to host this for testing purpose (for free). I'm unable to find a way to it. (I'm unfamiliar with Maven but I've converted my project to Maven project using eclipse.) I've uploaded my project to github using egit. I tried to use Heroku and Openshift but I couldn't figure a way to it. Can anyone explain in detail how to host it and configure mySQL.?

Also, I've a free domain (.tk) if it can be of any use.

Comment: Why don't you run a local web server and mysql (regular or as docker containers)?

Comment: What about a free-tier amazon EC2 instance?

Comment: @eol can you please explain how can I do it using AWS EC2

Comment: @rparree I want to host it on a server so that it can be tested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd set up an amazon EC2-instance, install Java and since you're using JSP a server that provides a servlet container and JSP-engine e.g. Tomcat. Export your application as a .war file, upload it to your remote machine and deploy it to your Tomacat server. 
Here's a nice tutorial which should help you setting it all up:

https://readlearncode.com/cloud/amazon-free-usage-tier-installing-tomcat-7-on-an-ec2-linux-instance/

---

EDIT

You need to set the correct permissions for tomcat's webapps directory. Per default it belongs to the root user, so you either do a `chmod -R 777 /opt/tomcat/webapps` which is unsafe

or

you set the tomcat group for the webapps directory:

```
chgrp -R tomcat /opt/tomcat/webapps

chmod -R g+w /opt/tomcat/webapps
```

For safety you can remove the write permissons after deploying:

```
chmod -R g-w /opt/tomcat/webapps
```

Also this link might help:
[Error while trying to deploy WAR on Tomcat8 on Ubuntu 15.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34642211/error-while-trying-to-deploy-war-on-tomcat8-on-ubuntu-15-04)

Comment: I went through the tutorial but it didn't worked out. This section didn't worked for me-
"Use Tomcat’s manager to launch a WAR file

Once the instance has rebooted, go to your browser and enter the public DNS of your instance followed by the port 8080. It should look something like this: ec2-XX-XXX-XX-XX.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080."

Comment: I'm unable to connect to Linux (Ubuntu) instance using browser. Launch SSH client button is not working on Firefox, Chrome doesn't support NPAPI. However, I'm able to connect to Windows 2012 Server instance.

Comment: You'd need putty or a similar ssh-client to connect to the machine. Once connected, install all required software, upload your .war file using (e.g. using sftp), and deploy it to your tomcat. After that you can access your application at `ec2-XX-XXX-XX-XX.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080`.

Comment: can you please brief how can I install software using putty? I've putty installed and I'm able to connect to the directory using winSCP tool. I also have war file. But I don't know how can I do it

Comment: If you're not familiar with a linux terminal using a windows machine is probably the better way. You can connect to it using RDP and have a GUI. If you still want to go with linux and the terminal this probably helps: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-7-on-ubuntu-14-04-via-apt-get

Comment: AWS "Lunch SSH Client using Java" isn't working. The possible reason I guess is, Chrome deprecated the NPAPI support as well as Microsoft Edge browser and Mozilla Firefox doesn't support 64 bit Java neither Opera. Can you tell any browser which supports Windows 10 64 bit with Java 64 bit.?

Comment: I've never used the remote terminal over  the browser. Just use Putty as a ssh client, it's really simple...and there are various tutorials on the web to set putty up for connecting to a aws machine.

Comment: I can connect to Ubuntu instance using putty but what to do after it?

Comment: Install Java (e.g. sudo apt-get install default-jdk), Tomcat (see link I posted above). Then use winSCP to upload your .war file and deploy it to your running tomact...

Comment: Thanks a lot. Everything worked except one thing. What is Server_IP_adress as said in tutorial? I tried to access tomcat in browser using   public_IP_of_amazon:8080   private_IP:8080   public_DNS:8080   private_DNS:8080  but none did opened Tomcat's web app manager page. I got error "This site can't be reached."
Also, this created so much confusion because previously Putty was not taking any input through keyboard in Amazon_linux instance. So I created a new instance of ubuntu and it worked now.

Comment: I added a security group with custom TCP for port 8080 and now I can access public_DNS:8080. But still, public_DNS:8080/admin or /manager/html or /docs or /examples are not working. I've installed them (sudo apt-get install tomcat7-docs tomcat7-admin tomcat7-examples)

Comment: Check out https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-ubuntu-14-04. You need to edit the tomcat-users.xml accordingly. Also I think instead of deploying your .war using the manager you can just copy the .war into the `webapps` folder inside the tomact directory (probably /usr/share/tomcat7/lib) and restart Tomcat.

Comment: This tutorial really worked.
I'm unable to upload war file from the manager app. I'm getting error "FAIL - Deploy Upload Failed, Exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/tomcat/webapps/ebank.war (Permission denied)"
I cannot upload war file using winSCP also. The directory is /opt/tomcat/webapps. I'm getting permission denied.